# What's the fastest way to run multiple php CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I need to move a lot of mysql rows to a couchbase server. The catch is that I need to use a PHP class to do the job (The class has business logic)

I've created a PHP ClI script and ran 6 of them at once. It's faster than running a single CLI script, but not enough. It took me 2 hours to transfer everything.

Are there any better way?

**Updated:**

What PHP code does with Mysql

1. select * from table limit $limit

That's about it. Nothing fancy.

Comment: The MySQL server will probably be the bottleneck.

Comment: What @Barmar said. You can use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to spin up more processes, but I'll wager you're going to cap out fairly early on I/O.

Comment: @Barmar // I don't think it is. I only use select statement to select rows. That's about it.

Comment: @Sammitch // What's the difference between supervisord and running multiple PHP Cli script?

Comment: @Moon So? They all have to be processed by the same `mysqld` server process, and they're all going to the same database file.

Comment: Nothing. It just helps you manage multiple processes at once.

Comment: @Barmar // When the first select happens (Select * from table limit 1000), I believe PHP stores those data in the memory. Doesn't it? Once they're in the memory, how does it affect the performance?

Comment: But if you have multiple scripts, all repeatedly doing hundreds of selects, they'll collide with each other on the server.

Comment: @Barmar // Not really. I've tested with 6 scripts. It's simple select with limit at the end. They're cheap. Once select loads data into the memory, Mysql's job is done. It should not be the bottleneck for the long running scripts.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have your answer. Just run more PHP scripts.

Comment: @Moon At how many parallel scripts does it start to get slower? When it gets slower, where do you see the bottleneck? I usually try 1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300 ... until I get over the limit.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any better way?

Yes. There most likely is.

You need to identify the bottleneck. From what you describe it seems the bottleneck is the number of jobs run in parallel. So you should increase that until you find the maximum performance. GNU Parallel can often help you do that.

When you have done that, the bottleneck is somewhere else. But since your description has very little detail, it is impossible to tell where.

You will therefore have to find the new bottleneck. The bottleneck is typically disk I/O, network I/O, or CPU, but can also be a shared lock or other ressource.

To look for a CPU bottleneck run `top`. If you see a process running at 100% and you cannot parallelize this process, then you have found your bottleneck.

To look for a disk I/O bottleneck run `iostat -dkx 1`. If the last column hits 100% more than 50% of the time, you have found your bottleneck.

To look for a network I/O bottleneck run `iotop`. If the bandwidth used is > 70% of the available network bandwidth, you have found your bottleneck.

A special network problem is DNS: This can often be seen as a process that is stuck for 5-10 seconds for no good reason, but which otherwise runs just fine. Use `tcpdump -s1000 -n port 53` and see if the questions are being answered quickly. Do this on all machines involved in running the job.

To look for the shared lock is harder. You will first have to find the suspect processes and then you have to `strace` these.